# Storing array of POJOs - What is the better option in java?

Tags: java, android, collections, pojo

I have POJOs parsed from JSON.

```
Account [] accounts; 

class Account {
  Integer number;
  String name;
  String location;
  Date started;
}
```

I get list of accounts from JSON API call. Jackson mapper maps the resulting JSON to above POJOs.
I will need to do searching and other operations on these objects.

I am not sure how to store these to do the searching and to display them (in Android).

```
ArrayList
Map
HashTable
...
```

etc. Searching should be fast. I get about 500 accounts on an average. Mapping is done and I have the objects in an array now. But not sure how to go from here.

More over, I am fairly new to Java Collections and Generics. So any code example with direction would help.

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of searches will you be doing?  Will be searching on all fields in all combinations?

Comment: Yes. Primarily on date fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're searching, and you can identify a single key on which to search, I'd recommend the `HashMap`, because it's O(1) for access if you have a key.

`HashTable` is JDK 1.0 vintage; don't choose that.

Here's an example, assuming that the number is unique and represents a good search choice:

```
Account a = new Account(123456);
Map<Integer, Account> accounts = new HashMap<Integer, Account>();
accounts.put(a.getNumber(), a);
```

To access, you use the number:

```
Account b = accounts.get(123456);
```

Comment: Thanks! Can I use this HashMap to populate the list in an Android Activity? I would be listing, lets say, Names in an Activity.

Comment: Also, how does it help, if I am going to search on Date field?

Comment: Better get a Map with a Date key, then.  You're only going to process one Account per Date?  Your bank can't make money like that, unless you keep Date down to the millisecond (or nanosecond).

Comment: Nope. Basically to search based on Date.

Comment: Date searches are range searches.  I would consider a tree-style index as opposed to a plain old map.  What kind of date searches are you going to try?  Before, after, and between?

Comment: @RayToal Yes, thats basically it.

Comment: @duffymo Sorry. I did not understand that. Can you elaborate? Or any example you can point me to?

Comment: I think a Google search for the Comparator should have done it.  Let me help you: http://www.javadeveloper.co.in/java-example/java-comparator-example.html

Answer (score 4):

Five hundred accounts is not really a huge number, and if your application is small and gets very little use (meaning it isn't a webservice with thousands of simultaneous queries), you just might be able to get away with linear searches.

Assuming that is not the case, and that seems like a good assumption, you should build **indexes** for those fields that you expect to query often.  If you will primarily search on name you can build a hashmap with the lowercased version of the name

```
nameIndex = new HashMap<String, Account>();
for (Account a : accountArray) {
    nameIndex.put(a.name.toLowerCase(), a);
}
```

Then for "exact name" searches lower case you search query then call `nameIndex.get`.

Searching by date is also possible, but here I would expect that you will be searching by date range.  In this case you might want to build an sorted list index or tree index.  Then you navigate the list or tree to find the desired range.

You can also do lookups by name regexes or my name proximity (bigrams, trigrams), there are lots of options.

BTW, databases do this kind of thing well.  You might consider just populating an embedded database like [H2](http://www.h2database.com/), though that might be overkill?  It's fun to learn, though.  Besides with a database you get the concurrency control and the caching for freeeeeeee!

TL;DR: build hashmap or treemap or plain sorted list indexes for queries you will use frequently make, and do linear search for complex custom queries.  Or, and this might be preferred: use an embedded database.

Comment: I am going to need to use this in Android. So sure if H2 is an option. I know we have SQlite. But I am wondering if thats the best option Performance wise.

Comment: SQLlite or H2 or any embedded database is attractive because you can let the database do the querying for you.  The database already solves the problem of range queries, partial text queries, etc.  It makes your job a zillion times easier.  But you mentioned this is going to be run on a single android device so there is no concurrency concerns.  And you only have 500 accounts?  My guess is simple searches with or without index structures will be fine, too.  If it is a single-user interactive application, don't worry about premature optimizations!